# Php Get incorrect ID

Tags: php, sql

I need to fetch the hotel with the correct hotel id, the code below it have some error while user select the hotel and display the wrong hotel information.

Here attached the error url: 
[Error url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXg6F.jpg)

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["result"]))
{
$search = $_REQUEST["result"];
$checkin = $_REQUEST["checkin"];
$checkout = $_REQUEST["checkout"];
$guest = $_REQUEST["guest"];

$query = "select * from hotel,room_type WHERE hotel.hotel_id = room_type.hotel_id and hotel.hotel_address LIKE '%".$search."%' or hotel.hotel_city LIKE '%".$search."%' or hotel.hotel_state LIKE '%".$search."%' or hotel.hotel_name LIKE '%".$search."%' AND room_type.room_available_from >='$checkin' AND room_type.room_available_till <='$checkout' AND room_type.room_guest = '$guest' group by hotel.hotel_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

}
```

Below is the code display the list of the hotel,it display same hotel_id:

```
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $hid = $row["hotel_id"];
       $url = 'hid='.$row["hotel_id"].'&checkin='.$checkin.'&checkout='.$checkout.'';
                ?>
       <div class="list-body" onclick="window.location.href='hotel.php?<?php echo $url ?>'">
                    <div class="col-photo">
                        <?php
                        $img_result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM hotel_images where hotel_id = $hid");
                        $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($img_result);
                        ?>
                        <img src="../img/hotel/<?php echo $r["hotel_image"]?>">
      </div>
      <div class="col-info">
            <div class="info-content">
            <div class="col-title">
                  <h3><?php echo $row["hotel_name"] ?></h3>
      </div>
```

Comment: You could get a performance boost here by doing a JOIN in the first query across to the hotel_images table, rather than querying the hotel_images table for every row.  Could you include a var_dump($row); within your while loop in the 2nd part of the script and let us know the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem lies in your sql.

```
select DISTINCT hotel.hotel_id, * from hotel
inner join room_type on room_type.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id
where (hotel.hotel_address LIKE '%".$search."%'
or hotel.hotel_city LIKE '%".$search."%'
or hotel.hotel_state LIKE '%".$search."%'
or hotel.hotel_name LIKE '%".$search."%')
AND room_type.room_available_from >='$checkin'
AND room_type.room_available_till <='$checkout'
AND room_type.room_guest = '$guest'
```

2 more things, tho:

- you should not do sql queries inside loops ($img_result should be outside the loop) as they are performance heavy (the db becomes the bottle.neck)
- your sql is vulnerable to sql-injection. you should use prepared statements (PDO) or a similar technique or atleast filter the user input